# Why is Chrome losing some background images in a PDF when retrieved remotely but not locally?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, mac

I posted a [9.1 MB, 58 page, PDF](https://www.sfmta.com/sites/default/files/reports-and-documents/2020/06/6-2-20_item_11_transit_recovery_plan_-_slide_presentation_-_final_draft_reduced.pdf) to our website.

The staff member who created the PDF reported to me that the image on the next to last page was not showing up, displaying a white background instead. They are using Chrome Windows.

I was able to reproduce this in Chrome Mac but not in Chrome Windows. On a later attempt in Chrome Mac, I lost the image on the last two pages, not just the next-to-last page.

However, if I download the file to my local machine, Chrome Mac doesn't lose the image either.

And if I do a diff on the file I originally uploaded to the website and the file I downloaded from the website through the Chrome Mac browser, they are, as expected, bit identical.

If I extract the page from the PDF and upload it to the website, it doesn't display the issue.

Why is the image disappearing and is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: FWIW it worked fine for me in FireFox on  Win10 - even without the commentary, interesting stuff in the slides

Comment: Hi Charles, do you feel as if my answer was helpful? If so, please don’t forget to mark my answer as "accepted" by clicking the gray checkmark to the left of the answer. If your question hasn't been fully answered, please elaborate on what else you need to know so the community can provide you with further help! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I managed to reproduce this on Chrome for Windows. The image on the second to last page doesn't show up, but when I download the .pdf and open it locally, it works fine. The image also shows up fine in Firefox either way.

However, if I try loading the PDF from a different server, it doesn't seem to have the same issue.

Since it seems to be working on a different server setup, that leads me to believe that it's a server-related issue. Is your Varnish reasonably up to date?

Comment: I'll check. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this for our business by using this code (thanks ChatGPT!) in the JS Puppeteer file:

await page.addStyleTag({ content: `@media print { html, body { -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact; background-color: #F1EEED; } }`});